# php, Where does the print statement print

Tags: php, printing

I'm making a modification to the following code.  I'm a newbie.
The code below is a short segment from a much longer code that scans a mySQL database every 5 minutes for specific events.  The event below is triggered if a stock price exceeds a preset set value.  Once the event is triggered a character string is constructed (called $body) and an email is sent.

The statement: "$body .="    makes sense to me and results in string of data that is eventually emailed.
The question is:  where does the "print" statement print. 
Is it going to a log.  It is not appearing on my computer screen anywhere.

```
if (!empty($symbol_alert['alert_buy_stop']) && (float)$symbol_alert['alert_buy_stop'] < (float)$unique_symbol_data[$symbol_alert['symbol']]['price']) {

print "Price 'Buy Stop' triggered for symbol_id -> {$symbol_alert['id']} for user_id -> {$symbol_alert['user_id']}".PHP_EOL;

$body .= 
'
Your BUY STOP price is: $'.number_format($symbol_alert['alert_buy_stop'],2);
                                $alerts_count++;
                        }
```

Comment: How are you running the script? Is it part of a web page, or do you run it from the CLI?

Comment: Does the script make use of the `ob_*` functions to control output buffering?

Comment: It's running on a web page   (myvaluealerts.net)

Comment: I don't see the ob_* function anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's a linux server, it sounds like a cron job running the script every 5 minutes.  The output is probably being redirected to a log file.  Take a look at the user's crontab (the user which is running the script).  At the end of the line there maybe a redirect >> /to/example/output.log

As the appropriate user, use **crontab -e** to view their cron jobs.

More on redirection here:  http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: yes, a cron job on the web page triggers the code at 5 minute intervals.

Comment: That makes no sense, cron jobs aren't on web pages. Cron jobs run in the background on the server, they don't have anything to do with web pages.

Comment: Sounds like the output of the script is being redirected (in the cron job where the script is called)

Comment: Are you confusing the web server with the web pages?

Comment: asdfqwerzxcv -  I'll read the info on the link you sent.  And yes, the server that hosts the web site is runing the Cron job.

Comment: @Dustin in the cron job, at the end of the script line you should see a redirection.  Example:  /path/to/your/script.php >> /path/to/logfile.log

Comment: Typically you would edit cronjobs with the crontab -e command via the command line over an ssh connection.  Does the web host have a control panel where you can edit cron jobs?

Comment: asdfqwerzxcv - yes, the web host has a control panel where I could edit the cron job.  This is the Cron job command line:    /usr/bin/php /home/myvalueadmin/public_html/check_alerts.php >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: I removed the ">/dev/null 2>&1" from the cron job.  That redirect sent the output to null heaven and prevented the cron job from sending me an email every time the job completed running.  The email I received contined the output of two of the 14 print statements.  Some of the print statements only occur in the event of an error.  I'll keep investigating, I would have expected no fewer than 4 print statements in the output.  Thanks for your help.  I'm getting closer.

Comment: It would redirect output of print, echo, or any html output but it would not affect the $body variable being sent in an email.  The email function, 14 print statements etc. are not noted in the question.

Comment: If you're looking to have those print statements as part of the email you would need to append them to the $body variable.  Instead of `print "something".PHP_EOL;` you could just `$body .= "something";`